# ui.Bootstrap.Collapse forces a submit in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a form that uses ui.bootstrap collapse, on selection it always submits, not sure why, here is my code:

### HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="update($event)">    
        <tabset>
            <tab heading="Restrictions">
                <div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Departments <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                    <div collapse="isCollapsed">
                        <div> Code to display departments </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>

        <br />
        <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

### angular JS :

```
angular.module('xTimeApp').controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});

$scope.update = function (event)
{
    var test = "Save my changes";
}
```

Comment: Why is your `$scope.update` function outside your controller?

Comment: Oh...sorry that was part of the top controller, I moved the stuff around in the mean time, now it does not occur anymore, so I think I  did something obviously incorrect, we can close this one

Comment: Ok...this happens only if I use a from element, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form but you just add the type="button" on the button for ui-collapse, else it will take the first button and think it's a submit button.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="update($event)">    
            <tabset>
                <tab heading="Restrictions">
                    <div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Departments <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                        <div collapse="isCollapsed">
                            <div> Code to display departments </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </tab>
            </tabset>

            <br />
            <div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanx Jowy, will try it